What does the number after the url function for the image property mean in a Qt5 QCSS specification?
Reading up on CSS stylesheet handling in Qt5, I found the following snippet at http://web.archive.org/web/20180629230221/http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15119-QSlider-custom-handle-image-not-displayed :
QSlider::handle:vertical {
    image: url(:/GenericWidget/Ressources/vcursor.png) 1;
    height: 14px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    margin-right: -6px;
}

Note that there is a number 1 after the url(...) CSS function for the image: CSS property. What does this number mean? I've read through

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#image-prop

... but I cannot see a mention (or an explanation) of any such number there.
I've found something similar mentioned in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html but for border-image - and there are actually four numbers there:
QPushButton {
    color: grey;
    border-image: url(/home/kamlie/code/button.png) 3 10 3 10;
    border-top: 3px transparent;
    border-bottom: 3px transparent;
    border-right: 10px transparent;
    border-left: 10px transparent;
}

Closest I could come to an explanation is this comment in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url :
/* ... */
/* Associated short-hand properties */
background: url('star.gif') bottom right repeat-x blue;
/* ... */

... ok, so probably those numbers after url() are shorthand - but in case of QCSS image:, shorthand for what?

I don't think that number does anything, in fact, it's probably ignored. Numbers are actually considered for the border-image property, indicating the size of the border sides.

Thanks @musicamante - I did some research which I documented in an answer below, and I agree with your explanation. Probably that snippet I found assumed wrongly the same attributes for border-image are also parsed for image

I did some research in Qt5 source, and I think the conclusion is the same as the comment by @musicamante. First of all, in https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.15/src/gui/text/qcssparser.cpp there is:
static const QCssKnownValue properties[NumProperties - 1] = {
// ...
    { "border-image", BorderImage },
// ...
    { "image", QtImage },
// ...

Note that border-image refers to a "custom" BorderImage, but image refers to a "base" QtImage; note BorderImage is simply a member of enum Property, which also has QtImage.
If we go on searching for BorderImage, we eventually find:

void Declaration::borderImageValue(QString *image, int *cuts,
                                   TileMode *h, TileMode *v) const
{
    const DeclarationData *d = this->d.data(); // make it const and shadow d
    *image = uriValue();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        cuts[i] = -1;
    *h = *v = TileMode_Stretch;

    if (d->values.count() < 2)
        return;

    if (d->values.at(1).type == Value::Number) { // cuts!
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < qMin(d->values.count()-1, 4); i++) {
            const Value& v = d->values.at(i+1);
            if (v.type != Value::Number)
                break;
            cuts[i] = v.variant.toString().toInt();
        }
        if (i == 0) cuts[0] = cuts[1] = cuts[2] = cuts[3] = 0;
        else if (i == 1) cuts[3] = cuts[2] = cuts[1] = cuts[0];
        else if (i == 2) cuts[2] = cuts[0], cuts[3] = cuts[1];
        else if (i == 3) cuts[3] = cuts[1];
    }
// ...

So, those four numbers after url() in border-image are likely cuts. But what do cuts refer to? That seems to be revealed in https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/5.15/src/widgets/styles/qstylesheetstyle.cpp :

void QRenderRule::drawBorderImage(QPainter *p, const QRect& rect)
{
    setClip(p, rect);
    static const Qt::TileRule tileMode2TileRule[] = {
        Qt::StretchTile, Qt::RoundTile, Qt::StretchTile, Qt::RepeatTile, Qt::StretchTile };

    const QStyleSheetBorderImageData *borderImageData = border()->borderImage();
    const int *targetBorders = border()->borders;
    const int *sourceBorders = borderImageData->cuts; // cuts HERE!!!
    QMargins sourceMargins(sourceBorders[LeftEdge], sourceBorders[TopEdge],
                           sourceBorders[RightEdge], sourceBorders[BottomEdge]);
    QMargins targetMargins(targetBorders[LeftEdge], targetBorders[TopEdge],
                           targetBorders[RightEdge], targetBorders[BottomEdge]);
// ...

Aha - so cuts have to do with sourceBorders in the case of border-image. But if, by analogy, we look up drawImage, we find the function:

void QRenderRule::drawImage(QPainter *p, const QRect &rect)
{
    if (!hasImage())
        return;
    img->icon.paint(p, rect, img->alignment);
}

... where there is no mention of cuts whatsoever. Which means, as @musicamante put it:

I don't think that number does anything, in fact, it's probably ignored. Numbers are actually considered for the border-image property, indicating the size of the border sides.

